# SQL - 1388 Character SQL Query. ( Must Be A Simpler Solution? )

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I've wrote an SQL query that should be simple, that turns out is not so simple. I have a database of 1.2 million words (several languages)+ more. My neice asked how many words I can make with 5 letters from the letters jxtehmrungce. I then decided to run a test. Well, turns out it's easy to write a query like this. However!~ There must be an easier solution? The more characters, the longer the query.

Below, it's looping through all characters (letters) in order of alphabet

> `` SELECT count(DISTINCT `word`) as `numrows` FROM `words` WHERE LENGTH(`word`) = '5' AND `chars` REGEXP '
>   ([g{0,1}+]|[i{0,1}+]|[l{0,1}+]|[m{0,1}+]|[n{0,1}+]|[o{0,1}+]|[r{0,1}+]|[t{0,1}+]|[u{0,1}+]|[x{0,1}+])+([g{0,1}+]|[i{0,1}+]|[l{0,1}+]|[m{0,1}+]|[n{0,1}+]|[o{0,1}+]|[r{0,1}+]|[t{0,1}+]|[u{0,1}+]|[x{0,1}+])+([g{0,1}+]|[i{0,1}+]|[l{0,1}+]|[m{0,1}+]|[n{0,1}+]|[o{0,1}+]|[r{0,1}+]|[t{0,1}+]|[u{0,1}+]|[x{0,1}+])+([g{0,1}+]|[i{0,1}+]|[l{0,1}+]|[m{0,1}+]|[n{0,1}+]|[o{0,1}+]|[r{0,1}+]|[t{0,1}+]|[u{0,1}+]|[x{0,1}+])+([g{0,1}+]|[i{0,1}+]|[l{0,1}+]|[m{0,1}+]|[n{0,1}+]|[o{0,1}+]|[r{0,1}+]|[t{0,1}+]|[u{0,1}+]|[x{0,1}+])+([g{0,1}+]|[i{0,1}+]|[l{0,1}+]|[m{0,1}+]|[n{0,1}+]|[o{0,1}+]|[r{0,1}+]|[t{0,1}+]|[u{0,1}+]|[x{0,1}+])+([g{0,1}+]|[i{0,1}+]|[l{0,1}+]|[m{0,1}+]|[n{0,1}+]|[o{0,1}+]|[r{0,1}+]|[t{0,1}+]|[u{0,1}+]|[x{0,1}+])+([g{0,1}+]|[i{0,1}+]|[l{0,1}+]|[m{0,1}+]|[n{0,1}+]|[o{0,1}+]|[r{0,1}+]|[t{0,1}+]|[u{0,1}+]|[x{0,1}+])+([g{0,1}+]|[i{0,1}+]|[l{0,1}+]|[m{0,1}+]|[n{0,1}+]|[o{0,1}+]|[r{0,1}+]|[t{0,1}+]|[u{0,1}+]|[x{0,1}+])+([g{0,1}+]|[i{0,1}+]|[l{0,1}+]|[m{0,1}+]|[n{0,1}+]|[o{0,1}+]|[r{0,1}+]|[t{0,1}+]|[u{0,1}+]|[x{0,1}+])+([g{0,1}+]|[i{0,1}+]|[l{0,1}+]|[m{0,1}+]|[n{0,1}+]|[o{0,1}+]|[r{0,1}+]|[t{0,1}+]|[u{0,1}+]|[x{0,1}+])+([g{0,1}+]|[i{0,1}+]|[l{0,1}+]|[m{0,1}+]|[n{0,1}+]|[o{0,1}+]|[r{0,1}+]|[t{0,1}+]|[u{0,1}+]|[x{0,1}+])' AND `verified` = '1' ``

I will be using this on [yougowords.com](http://www.yougowords.com) for the unscrambler tool against a 3.9 million row table if it works well, but it's a very time consuming query. How can I improve this? There are probably several regular expressions, but, if you change the set of characters to something with double or triple letters, such as adding an extra j,  g, h, or adding more letters etc. jjtehhmrungcs

**Edit**
 - No duplicating characters, hence why you see 2 e's in the characters, but not 2 t's. ( jxtehmrungce )

- {0,1} was a minimum to maximum setting since duplicate characters can have more than 1 and you can make a 5 letter word by using only 1 of the duplicated letters, or both of them. {0,1} could be written as {1,2} - but, also need to set a maximum amount of letters possible. The word can't have 3 e's because jxtehmrungce only has 2.

I have no SQL experience, I'm basing this example off of my own limited knowledge.

**Chars Column**
For a different program, I created the chars column for alphabetical organization of all letters in the word. So the word "life" in order is efil and the word happy would be ahppy. I could use either or column to get the same result with this query but the chars column places characters in order, so jxtehmrungce becomes ceeghjmnrtux. Could help with finding words that have "only" 2 e's?

Comment: Would a word such as "tenet" be allowed?  "t" only appears once in your list but twice in the word.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could provide a list of scenarios that are correct and also some that would be incorrect. As it is now, the question is a bit vague.

Comment: What are the `{0,1}+` supposed to do? Also when giving additional info, please *edit your question*, don't answer in the comments. They are *designed* to be impractical for this, editing the question will be easier for everyone. And if you could give us some example of words you want to match and words you don't, that'd be great.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know to add more info to the question, instead of the comments @Robin

Comment: No problem. The regex symbol `?` means "zero or one time" (so `{0,1}`), I believe it could lighten up your expression... Also I don't understand what you want the `+` in `{0,1}+` to do, but I'm fairly sure you don't need them.

Comment: What is the difference between the `word` column which is used in the select and `len(word) = 5,` and the `chars` column which is used in the RegExp comparison in your SQL example?  Should `chars` really be `word`?

Comment: For a different program @BateTech , I created the chars column for alphabetical organization of all letters in the word. So the word "life" in order is efil and the word happy would be ahppy. I could use either or to get the same result with this query but the chars column places characters in order, so jxtehmrungce becomes ceeghjmnrtux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on Gordon's awesome answer above, you could create a temp table that stores each char and the maxCount that each char should appear, and then use a `NOT EXISTS` sub-query in your where clause to check that each letter doesn't appear more than the maxCount.  I don't have MySQL installed to test this out, but my SQL Server version of this query worked and I think I have all the syntax converted to MySQL correctly.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE chars(letter char(1) not null, maxCount int not null);

INSERT INTO chars(letter, maxCount)
VALUES ('j',1),('x',1),('t',1),('e',2),('h',1),('m',1),('r',1),('u',1),('n',1),('g',1),('c',1) 
;

select count(distinct word)
from words w
where LENGTH(word) = 5 and word regexp '[jxtehmrungce]{5}' and verified = '1'
        and not exists(
            select 1 
            from chars c 
            --This checks how many times each character occurs in the word.
            --Ex: 'asdfee' has len = 6, if i replace the e's, then it becomes 'asdf' len = 4, 6 - 4 = 2
            where length(w.word) - length(replace(w.word, c.letter, '')) > c.maxCount 
        )
;
```

Here is a SQL Fiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0da4/2

You could also check into using GROUP_CONCAT (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to make the regular expression pattern dynamic. Here is an example that is dynamic based on the values in the char temp table and the values set for @targetWordLen variable.  This makes it easy to add new characters to the list and to change the target word length.

SQL Fiddle demo of the dynamic version: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0da4/29

```
SET @targetWordLen := 5;
set @regExPattern := concat('[',(select  group_concat(letter SEPARATOR '') from chars),']{', @targetWordLen, '}');

select count(distinct w.word)
from words w
where LENGTH(word) = @targetWordLen 
  and w.word regexp @regExPattern 
  and w.verified = 1
  and not exists(
            select * 
            from chars c 
            where length(w.word) - length(replace(w.word, c.letter, '')) > c.maxCount 
        )
;
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you want?

```
select count(distinct word)
from words w
where word regex '[jxtehmrungce]{5}' and verified = '1';
```

Or are you looking for permutations of the five characters?

EDIT:

If you are limited to the characters in the list, then you have a more complicated query.  I would take the approach of generating all possible combinations and then looking to see if they are words:

```
create view i_c as
   select 1 as i, 'j' as c union all
   select 2 as i, 'x' as c union all
   select 3 as i, 't' as c union all
   select 4 as i, 'e' as c union all
   select 5 as i, 'h' as c union all
   select 6 as i, 'm' as c union all
   select 7 as i, 'r' as c union all
   select 8 as i, 'u' as c union all
   select 9 as i, 'n' as c union all
   select 10 as i, 'g' as c union all
   select 11 as i, 'c' as c union all
   select 12 as i, 'e' as c;

select count(distinct w.word)
from i_c c1 join
     i_c c2
     on c2.i not in (c1.i) join
     i_c c3
     on c3.i not in (c1.i, c2.i) join
     i_c c4
     on c4.i not in (c1.i, c2.i, c3.i) join
     i_c c4
     on c5.i not in (c1.i, c2.i, c3.i, c4.i) join
     words w
     on concat(c1.c, c2.c, c3.c, c4.c, c5.c) = w.word
where w.verified = 1;
```

Comment: If this really works, I wish I could upvote about 10 times. Compared to the OP, this is the definition of elegance.

Comment: I understood the question as: a word of any length, composed by at most 5 different letters from the `jxtehmrungce` set. OP?

Comment: @Robin . . . I can see how you might make that interpretation.  But the `LENGTH(word) = '5' ` in the sample query suggests otherwise.

Comment: I believe Robin is correct. I know how this query is working - but it's finding all words with any of the 5 letters. It would need to display words that are 5 letters long from "only" the letters jxtehmrungce. No other letters should exist in the word. That's why my initial query is so congested. 

There are 2 e's in jxtehmrungce, so only words that have 2 e's and no more should appear, but can be 0 or 1 e, but must have the other characters as well.

Comment: The sample query shows
 ([g{0,1}+]|[i{0,1}+]|[l{0,1}+]|[m{0,1}+]|[n{0,1}+]|[o{0,1}+]|[r{0,1}+]|[t{0,1}+]|[u{0,1}+]|[x{0,1}+])+

it's saying, if there is 0-1 g or 0-1 m, etc. and then adding the same loop 5 more times (length of word), which finds first character being in the list, second character being in the list, third character and so on. Permutations, which I'll have to adjust later since I don't want to use the same character twice. And that's the second part of the problem.

Comment: Using your original statement, @GordonLinoff - with repetition - the following query does right. 

SELECT `word` FROM `words` WHERE LENGTH(`word`) = '5' AND `word` REGEXP '[ceeghjmnrtux]{5}' AND `verified` = '1' 

I guess all that's needed is a regexp that states only "1 c" and "2 e's" and "1 g" , etc. generating all possible combinations is an option and I'm working on it. But can it be simplified simply by using your original query?

Comment: @JamesCordeiro . . . If I could think of a way to create a simple regular expression for it, then I would not have added the edited code.